# How do I loop through and import the images of a certain digit from the MNIST database in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

In Netlogo, I would like to loop through and import all MNIST images of a particular digit one by one, having the turtles do some processing within every loop.

The closest I came to doing this is using import-pcolors, but this only imports a single image. I can't find any other relevant command.